# Laravel Why middleware didn't work in some apis

Tags: php, laravel

I defined two middleware: `EnableCORSRequest` and `EnableAllCORSRequest`.  `EnableCORSRequest` is  global middleware, I has been loaded it in `Kernel.php`.

part of the code of the `Kernel.php`

```
    $protected $middleware = [
        // ... other middleware
        EnableCORSRequest::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            // ... some middleware, I don't use web.php
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            'cors', // this is EnableCORSRequest
        ],

        'api_no_throttle' => [
            'bindings',
            'cors', // this is EnableCORSRequest
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // ... others
        'cors' => EnableCORSRequest::class,
        'no_cors' => EnableAllCORSRequest::class,
    ];
```

I use it in `api.php`:

```
// I don't want this api to be blocked by cors, so use this middleware
Route::post('/merchant/wallet/withdraw', 'Wallet@withdraw')
    ->middleware('no_cors');
```

But actually, `no_cors` didn't work, No error, No warning.
For test, I added log message in this two class

```
class EnableCORSRequest
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // add this const definition, because to avoid that if this middleware loaded after another one, the CORS option may be overwritten
        if(defined('ALLOW_CORS_REQUEST')){
            return $next($request);
        }

        \Log::info('enable_cors');

        // ......
    }
}



class EnableAllCORSRequest
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        define('ALLOW_CORS_REQUEST', 1);

        \Log::info('disable_cors');

        $response = $next($request);

        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Cookie, X-CSRF-TOKEN, Accept, Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization, authenticated');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

then I access this api by browser, And watch my log file, just `[2020-05-27 15:13:36] test.INFO: enable_cors`

Comment: I would do some tests like change name of middleware and see if there is an error 500.

Answer (score 1):

Middlewares working step by step and one by one So first global middlewares working 
and its seems always ALLOW_CORS_REQUEST neveer set when application go to EnableCORSRequest class because its running first so you should change your senario.

Comment: Yes, but it added the log in another one ,so I should see the `disabled_cors` log, but I didn't